# Unable to load URL https://getit-12.embarcadero.com when trying to load GetIt in Delphi 12

Tags: delphi, rad-studio, delphi-12-athens

Every time I open Delphi and try to load GetIt Packages on the Welcome Page, then I get an error and it doesn't load as can be seen by the image below:
[image]

Clicking on "Retry" doesn't work. Same issue.

The Warning/Error it gives me is:

> Unable to load URL https://getit-12.embarcadero.com. The following error occurred: Access violation at address 7A0E2732 in module 'rtl290.bpl'. Write of address 77C9BC5C

This happens every time. Is this a bug in Delphi 12 or perhaps my installation didn't complete properly? What can I do to fix GetIt and this Warning/Error?

Comment: Do you have any third-party IDE plugins? If not (and likely even if), this is a bug in RAD Studio. (And the worst possible kind of bug too.)

Comment: Please [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero

Comment: I don't have any third-party IDE plugins installed.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error just trying to install c++ Builder 12 via the webinstall.  Makes me think I should not bother.  Did you report the error, if so I'll add this instance as well

Comment: To add, I just tried GetIt in C++ Builder 11.3 (I had not done this in quite some time) and after a loooong wait I got an error 'getit-olympus.embarcadero.com server could not be reached'.  So they have server issues again .. why am I not surprised.

Comment: I couldn't find a bug report (not that I trust the interface's search, sigh) so I posted one (too), fyi : https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-44128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Version 12.0 GetIt is apparently now running again but versions prior to this are still unaccessible - thread has been opened with updates here on version 12.0 changes https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/10982-current-state-of-the-embarcadero-services/

Answer (score 4):

Got this answer from embarcadero's support team this morning (18.01.2024):

"Our servers are down, and this is causing the issue. We will notify you once the servers are back up, and running.
We have a blog about it here: https://blogs.embarcadero.com/we-are-experiencing-a-hardware-outage/ "

Waiting ....